# replace web traffic content with squid

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

I am using squid to block certain types of traffic to reduce band width, I have so far blocked adds, flash applications, video streaming and other such things. when a website or an advertisement becomes blocked my custom error page is displayed.

however, when I stop streaming from occurring the player just dies and I am left with a hollow video player is there anyway using squid (would prefer not to have to install multiple packages) that I can get the web video player to display a custom error?

on a side note when a specific ad comes up obviously my custom page gets shaped to fit the advertisements previous frame is there an easy way to just to get to removed rather than replace, for example ad blocker on google chrome removes them (if not im happy with replace just want it to look nice for my user)

thanks I look forward to some helpful replies.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do the node collapsing in HTML. This is easily done on the browser level when AdBlock has access to DOM and is able to remove/hide the HTML nodes where the ad will be displayed. In order to do that in Squid you need to use external ICAP server that processes the contents of HTML page and inserts/removes/hides the HTML nodes. Please take into account not all can be hidden though if for example node is dynamically constructed using in place or external JScript code. One of such ICAP servers is qlproxy.